# Counter for each table row which restarts on date change Mysql

Tags: mysql, count

I have the following mysql query that returns at counter as well as the results from the table, however I want the counter to restart whenever the date changes, can anyone assist in shedding some light in assisting, much appreciated

```
SELECT
@n := @n + 1 RowNumber,a.run_date

FROM (SELECT @n:=0 initvars),run_table a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT run_date,       
       @n := IF (@prev_date <> run_date, 
                IF( @prev_date := run_date, 1, 1), 
                @n + 1) AS RowNumber        
FROM run_table a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n:=0, @prev_date := '1900-01-01') initvars
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d1b9/1)

Comment: I am always amazed how the brain works, I am overly thankful @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: I usually use this format `SELECT run_date, @n := IF(@prev_date <> run_date, 1, @n+1) AS rowNum, @prev_data := run_date AS prevDate`. It adds an extra result field, but is a lot easier to follow (to me at least); and if you absolutely can't have the additional field, you can always turn it into a subquery with a simple wrapper SELECT query.

Comment: @dames Oh, make sure you `ORDER BY run_date`!